# Typically how much ram it takes to run a general Flask application?

Tags: python, flask, server, hosting, vps

Around how much ram it will take to run a normal flask just taking some data from SQLite / postgres database and serving to users. Approximately 100 daily active users (worst case scenario - 500) Can I expect it to only take 32-64MB ram (Total vps's ram is 1GB)?

2nd question : Will fastapi eat less ram than 100MB to do the same task?

Comment: In the case of 100 daily active users and for this usage, it's reasonable to assume that the RAM usage would be within the range of 32-64MB. Regarding FastAPI, it generally has a more efficient and performant design compared to Flask

Comment: Can you tell me how can I find out how much it takes to initialize flask application/package?

Comment: checkout the memory_profiler package